# conditional execution of playbook based on exit status of the command module?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to write a playbook which would execute some tasks only if a certain package is installed on the hosts.

Is it possible to register the output from a command module and run the tasks depending upon the exit status of the command ?

Something like this: 
[image: play tasks]

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right path. If httpd doesnt exist, the playbook execution will fail. You can use [ignore_errors](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_error_handling.html) to continue execution and then run subsequent tasks based on the return code of httpd_result. I have given an example below:

```
-  hosts: localhost
   tasks:
    - command: "which httpd"
      register: httpd_result
      ignore_errors: true
    - debug: msg="found http"
      when: httpd_result.rc == 0
    - debug: msg="not found httpd"
      when: httpd_result.rc!=0
```

Here, instead of debug statements, you can put whatever conditional tasks you need to run. Hope this helps.